# Why does method throw instead of returning null?

Tags: java, exception, throw

I was wondering why does some methods throw `Exception` instead of returning `null`?

For example `Class.forName(String className)` method throws `ClassNotFoundException`. If the callee wants to notify us why doesn't just return `null`, and we can check the result with an `if`, instead of having to write `try-catch` blocks.

Why isnt this written:

```
try{
    Class<?> c = Class.forName("foo.Bar");
} catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
    ...
}
```

like this:

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("foo.Bar");
if(c != null) {
    ...
} else {
    //handle that class wasn't found
}
```

Why is `Exceptions` used, when there could be a specific value to return (preferably `null` or sometimes `-1`), to notify the caller that the operation failed? I know if a method can fail more way, the caller could separate the reaction to it based on the error message, but in this case, the `ClassNotFoundException` is **only** thrown when the class couldn't be found.

And also there is the performance question, faster to return `null` than throw an `Exception` isn't it?

Comment: because that is exceptional condition for that method

Comment: `null` is not very informative, while an exception stacktrace often is quite informative and helpful.

Comment: Exceptions can provide more information (an error message) about what's wrong. The performance argument is irrelevant, this is unlikely to ever be a performance bottleneck in any program.

Comment: Exceptions also allow chaining to help debug really deep function call issues.

Comment: It throws because, as mentioned by Jigar, it is an abnormal case.  Accept that.  "there is the performance question" is as meaningful as "substitute a monkey hooting here".  The Java language is a high level language, in general the value of "high" is taken to be more important that the value of "I could save 12 cpu cycles by returning a goofball value instead of throwing an exception"

Comment: If you throw exceptions often they can be optimised and take around one micro-second.

Comment: Imagine a piece of code fails. Would you rather get debug info in the form of `null` or `-1` or something more informative like `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` which can show you when and where the problem occurred.

Comment: I think `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` is a more serious exception and the caller is not prepared for that, while you should prepare for a data query operation to fail, and check the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the caller's point of view, typically handing exceptions in a block of code is easier than checking return codes. For example, what if you wanted to call two functions that might fail? You then have something like:

```
if (functionAWorks()) {
  ...
  if (functionBWorks()) {
    ...
  }
  else {
    ...
  }
}
else {
  ...
}
```

instead of:

```
  try {
    functionA();
    functionB();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    ...
  }
```

Often the hassle of structuring return code handling results in people not checking the return codes at all.

From the callee's point of view, throwing an exception is often a cleaner way to indicate failure than returning a code, and it gives the caller stack trace information that can be very useful for debugging.

Performance is a different question. Arguably if you chose to use a managed language for your project, then you have already chosen not to worry about micro-performance issues.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that that method can also throw `LinkageError` or `ExceptionInInitializeError`. You might want to decide to perform different actions for different exceptions.

I agree with the comments that returning an exception is more informative than just returning null, and also on the fact that you shouldn't worry about performance.

Not related to this case, but for cases where only one exception is thrown, it would be fine to return null instead. Is it an exception not to find something requested? an abnormal case? then throw an exception... is it just a normal case? return null. It's a design choice and in any case it should be very well documented what the expected outcome of calling a method is. Documentation is like a contract between whoever implemented the method and the one calling it.

Moreover, in languages like Scala it's possible to call a method that returns an `Option`, which can have a value or None, in case the method didn't find what to return.

Comment: As in the documentation, "An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch.", so you can't really prepare for that. I agree with the 2nd part of your answer.

Comment: @Sipka I agree with you. However I have no idea what the OP is doing, maybe he's implementing an IDE where catching those error makes sense :)